# How to create a persistent iframe that does not refresh with the main page while using Go html templates?

Tags: javascript, html, go, iframe, go-templates

I am trying to create a streaming music web application and I want the iframe to be the music player and sit on top of the main website. I am new to GO and normally in HTML I would just create an iframe and use JS to send instructions. However, I am using GO templates and a base layout. Whenever I load the iframe into the base template it still refreshes the iframe at render of each template. How can I get the main website and iframe to load together but have the iframe persist through each page?

Here is my Main.go file:

````
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"
)

// Function defining the Home page. Connected to HandleFunc in main function.
func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderTemplate(w, "home.page.tmpl")
}

// Function defining the Explore page. Connected to HandleFunc in main function.
func Explore(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderTemplate(w, "explore.page.tmpl")
}

// Function defining the Library page. Connected to HandleFunc in main function.
func Library(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderTemplate(w, "library.page.tmpl")
}

// Function defining the Upload Music page. Connected to HandleFunc in main function.
func Upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderTemplate(w, "upload.page.tmpl")
}

// Function defining the About page. Connected to HandleFunc in main function.
func About(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderTemplate(w, "about.page.tmpl")
}

// Function defining the About page. Connected to HandleFunc in main function.
func Contact(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderTemplate(w, "contact.page.tmpl")
}

// Function for rendering the templates. Parsing the template. Checking for errors.
func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string) {
    parsedTemplate, _ := template.ParseFiles("./templates/"+tmpl, "./templates/base.layout.tmpl")
    err := parsedTemplate.Execute(w, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error parsing template", err)
        return
    }
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", Home)           //Root directory. Home page. localhost:8080.
    http.HandleFunc("/explore", Explore) //Explore page. In browser is localhost:8080/explore.
    http.HandleFunc("/library", Library) //Library page. In browser is localhost:8080/library.
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", Upload)   //Upload Music page. In browser is localhost:8080/upload.
    http.HandleFunc("/about", About)     //About page. In browser is localhost:8080/about.
    http.HandleFunc("/contact", Contact) //Contact page. In browser is localhost:8080/contact.

    //File-System to serve the assets to the client from the assets folder (CSS, JS, Images, Files, etc.)
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets"))
    http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", fs))

    //Starts web server on localhost:8080 in browser. To stop go to terminal where you opened the server and hit Ctrl + C when done.
    _ = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}```
````

Comment: I'm not familiar with Go, but assuming it produces plain HTML output, then you can't do what you're attempting. The iframe is a child of the parent window, so when the window is refreshed all child content is unloaded and re-loaded once more. If you're trying to build a site that plays music as you browse, something like the Spotify web player, then look in to how to create a Single Page Application (aka, an SPA) which utilises AJAX to load content dynamically.